# React Native: Unable to display image downloaded from Amazon AWS S3

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I have seen other answers on Stack Overflow for this, but still I am unable to resolve the issue.

If I download a JSON file, I am able to successfully read the contents. See below code:

**BELOW CODE WORKS FINE WHEN I DOWNLOAD JSON TEXT FILE FROM AWS S3**:-

```
    var result = await Storage.get('simplejsonfile', { 
                                                        level: 'private', 
                                                        cacheControl: 'no-cache',
                                                        download: true 
                                                    }); 
    var user_data = await new Response(result.Body).json();
    console.log(user_data);                  // this displays the JSON correctly. Works Fine !
```

The above code snippet just establishes that all my configurations are correct, because I am correctly able to download JSON file from AWS S3 using amplify and then read it.

**THE PROBLEM (WHEN I DOWNLOAD IMAGE I AM UNABLE TO DISPLAY IT LATER)**:-

I have an image abc.png on AWS S3 bucket. I have manually uploaded this image. I try to download and display on my mobile device. Its not working.

Also see the comments in code below:

```
                const [mystate, setTheImage] = useState();

...

                const getResponse = await Storage.get('abc.png', { 
                                                        level: 'private', 
                                                        // cacheControl: 'no-cache',
                                                        contentType: 'image/png',
                                                        // contentType: string,
                                                        download: true
                                                        });

                        var mydata = await new Response(getResponse.Body).text();
                        console.log(String(mydata));   //displays star & diamond symbols and PNG prefix on console
                        setTheImage(mydata);           // set state mystate
```

later ...

```
<Image source={{uri:mystate}} style={{ width: '100%', height: '60%' , resizeMode: 'contain' />
```

But I am unable to display the image. Preferably I only want to work with amplify library and dont want to install any more extra library just for this.